# Proof verification - Pigeonhole principle.

Tags: proof-verification, pigeonhole-principle

The question goes like this:

There are $16$ **different** integers $a_1...a_{16}\;$ such that foreach $i\; , $ $1\leq i \leq 16\;$ :$1\leq a_i \leq 30\;$.

Prove that there is a pair $a_i,a_j$ such that $a_i + a_j = 31$.

My proof:

There are $\binom{16}{2} = 120$ options to chose a pair, and only $(30+29)-(1+2) = 56$ possible sums.

$\left \lfloor \frac{120}{56} \right \rfloor = 2$

Due to the pigeonhole principle, we must have a pair $a_i,a_j$ such that $a_i + a_j = 31$ because each possible sum must contain a pair.

Is this a legit proof (logically speaking)?

Comment: Counting the total number of different pairs is more relevant when checking whether there must be two pairs that sum to the same thing, not when checking whether there must be one pair that sums to some given number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged it as pigeonhole principle, so making concrete pigeonholes might be a good idea. You are looking for pairs that sum to $31$, so those stand out as a natural choice. We then get the pigeonholes
$$
\{1,30\}, \{2,29\}, \ldots, \{15,16\}
$$
Now apply the principle, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

To see if it makes sense logically, first ask yourself these questions:

- What is the significance of the number $\left \lfloor \frac{120}{56} \right \rfloor$?
- What does it mean for a sum to "contain a pair"?

If you are struggling with the questions, then perhaps your proof is not complete. Or you might need to find another way to solve it. (Hint: find the smallest pair of numbers that sum to 31, is there any pair $(a_i,a_j)$ that could equal these numbers?)

Comment: @ Think of the sums as pigeonholes and think of the pairs as pigeons..

Comment: @vpam: sure, you can do that. And that shows that at least one "sum" must contain at least two pairs. But it says nothing about the particular sum "31", which might contain no pairs, while some other "sums" contain 5 or 6.

Comment: @vpam How does that tell you that there must be a sum equal to 31? 

It actually says that some of those sums have the same value (e.g., $1+4=5$ but also $2+3=5$).

Answer (score 0):

Your solution does not work. At most it shows that for possible sums the *average* number of pairs that sum up to that sum exceeds $2$. That does not prove that this is especially the case for sum $31$.

---

Assume that there is no such pair.

Then for each of the following $15$ pairs at least one of the members is not in the set $\{a_i\mid i\in\{1,\dots,16\}\}$:

$$\{1,30\},\{2,29\},\dots,\{15,16\}$$

But if $15$ numbers of $\{1,\dots,30\}$ are deleted then only $15$ will remain.

One too short to fill up the set $\{a_i\mid i\in\{1,\dots,16\}\}$ which has $16$ elements.

Proved is now that the assumption is false.